# Where to put the data in Azure for an ElasticSearch installation?

Tags: azure, elasticsearch

I would like to deploy an ElasticSearch cluster in Azure. I found some articles explaining how to configure the VMs for it and looks pretty easy. They use the VM "hard disk" to store the data.

I would prefer to separate the VM with the operating system and the ElasticSearch installation from the data storage. I could upgrade the VMs to bigger ones if needed or just use more storage independtly. Where and how should I configure it? I am a little bit lost about all the different storage options in Azure. I suppose that I need something like a virtual "hard disk" for ElasticSearch. Thank you for any answer or thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

I too was a little confused then I realised what was needed. When you spin up a new VM, two drives are present on it.

The first drive is the relatively small OS drive. This is persisted to a cloud storage virtual disk (VHD) stored in a cloud storage container you specified, or automatically created when you started a VM. Any changes (e.g., install elasticsearch) you make to this disk will always be saved. However, since this drive is relatively small, there isn't much space available - so it's not best practice to store application data on it.

The second drive is the temporary local storage provided with the VM (e.g., 
100gb SSD for a D2 VM). This is a drive situated in the physical machine itself, so it's typically fast as there is no network latency to access it. However, this is really intended for temp working data because it is *transient*. That is, if your VM gets migrated to another physical server in the cloud - perhaps after scaling or hardware failure - you will lose all the data on it because it resides inside one physical machine only. That is not good news if it contained your index!

The solution therefore is to create a disk that is stored in the cloud (just like the aforementioned OS disk), so that any index data is stored separately from the physical machine that is hosting the VM at any one moment in time. If your VM is moved to another physical machine, the local storage will be wiped, but your additional disk containing the index will be re-attached in its previous state, ready for ES to continue.

To add a new/empty disk to an existing Linux VM following this tutorial: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-how-to-attach-disk/. Once the disk is added, you will need to go into your elasticsearch.yml file and set the path.data to wherever you choose the mount the additional disk.

Answer (score 1):

You should add an additional disk to your Azure VM, and then configure Elasticsearch to store the data there.

Depending on your budget you could do this with a standard VM, or go with a DS series VM which will give you the possibility of adding a Premium disk which will give you much better (more predictable and reliable) performance.

If that premium disk is still not fast enough for your needs, then you can stripe within Azure or get Elasticsearch to stripe the data over multiple disks.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, how can i add a disk? Is this any of the storage options? (Table, blob, ...) please forgive me, but i am quite confused about the offerings